# Is a properly made website with more content has advantage in SEO?

Tags: seo, content

Somewhere I was reading about SEO and it was noted that for search engines, it is beneficial if a website has:

- Many pages within
- Long pages (~pages filled with a lot of content)

Of course these mean nothing if the given site looks like spam. But if we assume, this isn't the case, and the website is actually filled with a lot of text, on a lot of *potentially useful* pages (e.g. blogs, Wiki sites), then does this mean an advantage in SEO?

Comment: There is always a healthy medium. Too little content does nothing. Too much and Google looks at your site twice and three times. Content that is too short does nothing, too long, the same thing. Sites with little content cannot hope to attract search traffic. Too much and any site would be discounted. Just be natural and create content as you would want to see if you were visiting your site. Do not sweat all the SEO horse pucky you will find all over the place.

Comment: @closetnoc This is why I'm asking: naturally, my site would have quite a lot of pages with varying content (it's a Wiki-like one), I wanted to be sure that if I constantly expand it content-wise than that'd help the site getting better rankings.

Comment: There is a point where the original topic of the page begins to become diluted. This is where I draw the line. I create a focused topic for a page then begin writing. I tend to get carried away and have to scale back the content often. No surprise. But that also allows me to create more focused pages and better focus the pages that exist. As long as you keep *lean and mean* as a motto for creating content pages, you can wander all over the place and still have enough pages and content per page. The good news is that search is very forgiving. You can make mistakes and still do well.

Comment: Human readable, useful and unique, no TLDR;

Comment: [It's not about how much or How many content affect SEO](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-how-much-many-17821.html), it should be quality content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As closetnoc states, you need to draw the line.

Google can qualify too little content (I'm assuming under 250 words) as "thin content" and not index it as it offers no value to visitors.

Too much content might cause visitors to back out of the page sooner before seeing the remainder of the content (depending on the visitor's willingness to read novels).

In fact, I tested my homepage on powermapper tools (at try.powermapper.com) and it complained about me having more than 30 paragraphs on my home page (probably because of the large number of paragraph tags separating content).

The point is, try to **make your content rich** with at least 200 words and that spell out what the user is looking for and run it through a keyword density checker to ensure the most important sets of words are the most dense set of keywords, but don't make it sound unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that number of pages and amount of content counts for Google. But what's more important is to remember about the quality of the content on your website.